# dynamic filter for osgi component factory

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, karaf

I am trying to implement a component factory with dynamic filter as similar to service factory.

factory class

```
@Component(name = "ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider1", factory = "example.factory.provider")
public class ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider1 implements ExampleFactoryService {
```

While retrieving my factory i can retrieve by using reference

```
@Reference(target="component.factory=example.factory.provider" bind="setXXX" unbind="unsetXXX")
```

The above works fine which is in a static way. Can anybody tell is it possible to retrieve through dynamic way.

```
Dictionary<String, String> hashMap = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        hashMap.put("component.name", "ExampleComponentFactoryServiceProvider");
        instance = factory.newInstance(hashMap);
        service = (ExampleFactoryService) instance.getInstance();
```

Is it possible to retrieve in dynamic way?
If yes, can anybody please tell how to retrieve by component name/factory?

Comment: What do you mean by the "dynamic way"? Your code snippet using `factory.newInstance` is using a ComponentFactory to create an instance of the component.

Comment: ie) how to create a componentfactory instance by providing the filter. In the above code i have to give through reference which i can't change through compile time. Dynamic means i have give the filter on the fly with component name so that the componentfactory instance should be created as shown in the last snippet. By providing the values through dictionary.